# Date picker auto close after selecting the date is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have developed a type-form where i am using datepicker but after selecting the date , datepicker auto is not working

```js
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });

 $('select').material_select();
```

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    padding: .5714285714285714rem;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #464646;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    -o-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
```

```html
            <div class="input-group noEnter">
                <label for="basic-url">Date of birth</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"> </div>
```

please how i can solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any references to the pickadate library's theme CSS files in your snippet. It's autoclosing for me once I added them

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding: .5714285714285714rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #464646;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  transition: border-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/amsul/pickadate.js/master/lib/compressed/themes/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/amsul/pickadate.js/master/lib/compressed/themes/default.date.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amsul/pickadate.js/master/lib/compressed/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amsul/pickadate.js/master/lib/compressed/picker.date.js"></script>
<div class="input-group noEnter">
  <label for="basic-url">Date of birth</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```